# asome javascript code working, some of it not

Tags: javascript

I'm way over my head here, but I'm learning javascript and wanted to add a cool feature to a website I'm building for my wife's birthday as well as push myself further into the language.

I pulled the code from a website tutorial and the code works just fine there. The HTML and CSS are perfect on my site, but the javascript isn't complying. I have a JS code for another feature and that works just fine but the code from the tutorial doesn't work and I was wondering if this had something to do with the two separate JS codes competing against each other or not written correctly together within the JS file.

There are hammer.js files which I admittedly know very little about.

Like I said, it's for my wife's birthday and just wanted to add this feature while pushing me deeper into javascript.

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Here is the JS file with the two separate functions:

```
$(".question").click(function() {
    $(this).next().fadeToggle("fast");
    $(this).children();
});




$(function() {

    var $wrapper= $( '#fc-wrapper' ),
        $handle = $wrapper.children( 'div.fc-handle-pull' );

    $handle.on( 'click', function( event ) {

        ( $handle.data( 'opened' ) ) ? close() : open();

    } );

    $wrapper.hammer().bind( 'dragend', function( event ) {
        switch( event.direction ) {
            case 'right'    : open(); break;
            case 'left'     : close(); break;
        }
    });

    function open() {
        $wrapper.addClass( 'fc-wrapper-open' );
        $handle.data( 'opened', true );
    }

    function close() {
        $wrapper.removeClass( 'fc-wrapper-open' );
        $handle.data( 'opened', false );
    }

});
```

Here is how it's linked in the html file. I'm just posting the script links as everything else seems to work fine. As stated above, all the codes are taken from a tutorial that works as it's supposed to, just the question is not concerning the code itself, but how it is layed out in the files or how it is linked or if there are any links missing.  :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="hammer.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.hammer.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>


    </body>
</html>
```

HTML:

```
<div class="fc-wrapper">

    <!-- right-most handle piece -->
    <div class="fc-handle fc-handle-pull"></div>

    <div class="fc-perspective">

        <!-- right part overlay; get's darker -->
        <div class="fc-overlay fc-overlay-reverse"></div>

        <!-- middle handle piece -->
        <div class="fc-handle fc-handle-out"><div></div></div>

        <!-- inner bottom content part -->
        <div class="fc-bottom">
            <div class="fc-bottom-bg">
                <div class="fc-content">
                    <p>I can live with doubt, and uncertainty, and not knowing. I think it's much more interesting to live not knowing than to have answers which might be wrong. <span>Richard Feynman</span></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fc-overlay fc-overlay-solid"></div>
        </div><!-- //fc-bottom -->

        <!-- front and back of the flipping half -->
        <div class="fc-flip">

            <div class="fc-front">

                <div class="fc-inner">

                    <div class="fc-overlay fc-overlay-left"></div>
                    <!-- left-most part of handle -->
                    <div class="fc-handle fc-handle-in"><div></div></div>

                    <div class="fc-content">
                        <h3>Dubai</h3>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div><!-- //fc-front -->

            <div class="fc-back">

                <div class="fc-inner">

                    <div class="fc-content">
                        <div class="feynman">
                            <span>1918 – 1988</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="fc-overlay fc-overlay-right"></div>

                </div>

            </div><!-- //fc-back -->                 

        </div><!-- //fc-flip -->                 

    </div><!-- //fc-perspective -->

</div><!-- //fc-wrapper -->
```

jquery.hammer.js file:

```
/*
 * Hammer.JS jQuery plugin
 * version 0.3
 * author: Eight Media
 * https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js
 */
jQuery.fn.hammer = function(options)
{
    return this.each(function()
    {
        var hammer = new Hammer(this, options);

        var $el = jQuery(this);
        $el.data("hammer", hammer);

        var events = ['hold','tap','doubletap','transformstart','transform','transformend','dragstart','drag','dragend','swipe','release'];

        for(var e=0; e<events.length; e++) {
            hammer['on'+ events[e]] = (function(el, eventName) {
                return function(ev) {
                    el.trigger(jQuery.Event(eventName, ev));
                };
            })($el, events[e]);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: The javascript is making a number of references to classes that should exist in your html.  It's going to be very difficult to help without being able to see if your html is correct

Comment: When you remove all the blabber from your post, you're left with: this is my code, I copied some of it from a tutorial, it doesn't work. No information, no question. [StackOverflow isn't a forum.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115/302323)

Comment: What error are you receiving? What about it is not working?

Comment: @jwdwsn click the "edit" link at the bottom left of your question and insert the html in there

Comment: @Tibrogargen I have posted the HTML in the question section. Thanks.

Comment: @JasonYost Not getting an error message. The intended function just isn't happening as it should.

Comment: @jwdwsn Ok, so you're linking 4 different script files.  The 1st jquery one is fine, but there should be the following files in the same directory as your html file: `hammer.js`, `jquery.hammer.js` and `index.js`, but you only have javascript posted for one file.  Which one is it & what's in the others?

Comment: @Tibrogargan I've added the jquery.hammer.js file in the original question. I also have a hammer.js file which is really long. Not sure if it's necessary to post it, but I do have both files in the project folder.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Also, the index.js was posted in the original question, so that covers all four script links

Comment: @jwdwsn Ok, got your code running with no errors, but it's doing nothing (same as for you).  Here's the real question: __*What's it supposed to be doing?*__.  You have this code that refers to a "question" class, but there is nothing in your HTML that uses that class.  If we knew what behavior was expected it might be possible to figure something out.

Comment: @Tibrogargan The "question" class deals with another page altogether and it regards a sliding question and answer section. I didn't make myself clear in my original post. The code that doesn't work is supposed to open up the apply the fc-wrapper-class in the HTML provided. Hopefully, that helps. If not, I may have to try something else. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, another big problem is that what you have posted does not look anything like the tutorial.  I'm assuming there's a whole slew of CSS that you didn't put in your question.  I suspect the most important thing is that you have removed the `id="fc-wrapper"` from the fc-wrapper `div`.  Change `<div class="fc-wrapper">` back to `<div id="fc-wrapper" class="fc-wrapper">` and see what happens

Comment: @Tibrogargan Thanks for trying. The code is exactly like the code I have. It's a cut and paste job, except that I forget one line of CSS. But I went back over it line by line and it was all there. In any event, I really appreciate your time working with me.

Comment: @jwdwsn comparing the source of [3D Flipping Circles](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/3DFlippingCircle/) and what you have posted, it's plainly obvious that the "fc-wrapper" `div` has had the `id` attribute removed.  This is breaking the code.  The selector it's using is "'#fc-wrapper" which literally means "The element with id 'fc-wrapper'" - but that no longer exists.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Thanks so much for the advice. Really helped. The code that was given was not in the code within the instructions. But I Inspected the webpage itself and there was the id you mentioned along with another class (.fc-wrapper-open) that was not mentioned in the instructions. Now I have it opened, I just have to find out how to toggle it. But I'll inspect the page itself from now on. Huge help. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try moving the following code into `$(function`

```
$(".question").click(function() {
    $(this).next().fadeToggle("fast");
    $(this).children();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

did you try moving the javascript declaration on HTML of jquery.hammer.js before of hammer.js?

Comment: Hugo, just tried that. Didn't solve the issue, though.

Answer (score -2):

Remove the $ from the beginning of your IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) and add opening and closing parens at the end.

```js
(function() {

    var $wrapper= $( '#fc-wrapper' ),
        $handle = $wrapper.children( 'div.fc-handle-pull' );

    $handle.on( 'click', function( event ) {

        ( $handle.data( 'opened' ) ) ? close() : open();

    } );

    $wrapper.hammer().bind( 'dragend', function( event ) {
        switch( event.direction ) {
            case 'right'    : open(); break;
            case 'left'     : close(); break;
        }
    });

    function open() {
        $wrapper.addClass( 'fc-wrapper-open' );
        $handle.data( 'opened', true );
    }

    function close() {
        $wrapper.removeClass( 'fc-wrapper-open' );
        $handle.data( 'opened', false );
    }

})();
```

Comment: His usage is just an alias for [DOM ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).  There is a large chance your change would fail badly since the DOM would probably not have loaded when it was evaluated

Comment: John, this didn't work for me, unfortunately. Thanks for the suggestion, though.